# How to handle browser invocation in parallel tests using TestNG

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I have been using browser invocation in `@Beforeclass` TestNG method using the parameter passed from `testng.xml`. Once the browser is invoked, I am using login test in a `@BeforeMethod` which is required for all the other `@Test`s to start. But with this setup, I am unable to run the tests in parallel. I am seeing one browser is open and login tests which is required by both tests are run in same browser and fails. All my tests are in single class file. Code structure is as below:

```
public class MainTest {
    WebDriver driver;
    BrowserFactory browser;
    ReadData crmdatafile;


    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)    
    public void setup(ITestContext context) throws Exception{
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("datafile.txt").getFile());

        crmdatafile = new ReadData(file.getAbsolutePath());
        browser = new BrowserFactory(context.getCurrentXmlTest().getParameter("Selenium.browser"));
        driver = browser.getNewBrowser();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.get(crmdatafile.data.get("enviornment", "url"));
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
    }

    @BeforeMethod()
    public void login(){
        System.out.println("contains the code for login which needs to be run before every test");
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void afterEachTest(ITestResult result) throws IOException {
        driver.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void Test1() {   
        System.out.println("Will run login and next steps");
    }

    @Test
    public void Test2() {   
        System.out.println("Will run login and next steps");
    }

   public class BrowserFactory {

 private WebDriver driver;
 private  String browser;


    public BrowserFactory(String browser) {
        String brow=browser.trim().toLowerCase();
        if(!(brow.equals("firefox") || brow.equals("ff") || brow.equals("internetexplorer") || brow.equals("ie") || brow.equals("chrome") || brow.equals("gc"))) {
            browser="ie";
        }
        this.browser = browser;
    }

    public  WebDriver getNewBrowser() {
        String brow = browser.trim().toLowerCase();
        if(brow.equals("firefox") || brow.equals("ff")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
             DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
             capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
            driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            return driver;
        }else if(brow.equals("internetexplorer") || brow.equals("ie")){
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            return driver;
        }else if(brow.equals("chrome") || brow.equals("gc")){
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
             DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
             ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
             options.addArguments("test-type");
             capabilities.setCapability("webdriver.chrome.binary","drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
             capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
             driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
             driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            return driver;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

How can I improve the above structure to run tests in parallel and using a different browser for each test?

Comment: From what I see I assume that you have custom implementation of how you start your browsers, could you please show us BrowserFactory implementation?

Comment: I have included BrowserFactory  class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test code has some issues.
You are instantiating a webdriver instance in your `@BeforeClass` annotated method and that is being shared by all your `@Test` annotated test methods. You are also invoking `driver.close()` in an `@AfterMethod` annotated method.This is a recipe for disaster because AFAIK `driver.close()` is equivalent to `driver.quit()` if you are having only one web browser instance. So what this means is that your second test method will not have a valid browser (if you are running sequentially).

If you are running in parallel, then all your test methods are going to be competing for the same browser, which is now going to cause race conditions and test failures.

You should ideally speaking move the logic of your `setup()` method into a listener which implements `IInvokedMethodListener` interface and then have this listener inject the webdriver instances into a `ThreadLocal` variable, which your `@Test` methods can then query.

You can refer to [my blog post](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2013/07/31/parallel-webdriver-executions-using-testng/) which talks in detail on how to do this.

Please check if that helps.

Comment: Your blog looks very good with all detailing. I will go through them and let you know if any issues. Can you also let me know how can i pass dataprovider as keyset value.

Comment: I didnt quite get your question. Where do you want to pass a keyset ? Maybe you should create a new question for that..

Answer (score 0):

Here is the thing, as far as I can see you're not using annotations right and (probaly) testNG as well.

1. If you want to create browser instance before each test you may want to use `@BeforeTest` annotation. Also you may perform your test set up in this method as well. `@BeforeClass` annotation will be executed only once before this particular class will be executed.
2. It's a good idea to split tests that do different things into separate test files, case your tests do almost the same, but say params for tests are different - it's a good idea to use `@DataProvider`. Otherwise maybe you may want to extend your basic test with setup.
3. If you just want to re-execute same tests, but with different browser - consider relaunching your test job with different params or using @DataProvider as described above.
4. As far as I remember there are several ways to run testNG in parallel: Methods, Classes, Tests, Instances - figure out which one you need and which one works better with your setup.

Comment: I want to run testng with parallel tests. I agree with you to start using dataprovider as i need to run same test with different data. can you provide me inputs on how i can pass keyset name(from wini datafile) to `@test`. I am using `@beforeclass` to invoke the browser instance and @beforemethod to run the login test which is prerequisite for all my `@test`. so once the test is completed , it closes and browser and next `@test`again runs the login test under `@beforemethod `